# Ag-grid should gridApi?.deselectAll always trigger onSelectionChanged and onRowSelected events

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-react

When calling deselectAll() from grid-api, should it always trigger onRowSelected or onSelectionChange? Even when there's no actual changes in selected rows?

Comment: When it comes to producing events, I've often found that there's a difference between what you would logically expect and what ag-grid does. And this also varies between versions. So, in any given version, if the events aren't what you want, you generally have to come up with your own work-around for this sort of behavior, like possibly keeping track of row selections yourself.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Noticed different behaviour with events between ag-grid versions. Good to know it isn't just me experiencing this 